# UIScrollView wheel effect

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I need a scrollview in my iPad application that has two specific features, one of them is easy to find on much sample projects that is infinite scrolling. 
The second feature is, which is the problematic one, i need that scrollview seems as a circle (like a wheel) with a 3D depth effect, the current page is on tap of the screen with a big frame, and others can still be seen at the back, like far away in depth.

You can see what i mean in this review video of TNT for iPad app.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pv5EYliCciU

Any idea will be greatly appreciated,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After EricLeaf's answer i moved my focus on animating those windows and found a solution on the net.
You can find the sample code [here](http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/jason_harwig/coreanimation_image_carousel.html)

Basically;
As the above sample does, i use a uiview as the container instead of uiscrollview and custom layers for my views. Catch pangesturerecognizer and concat rotation and translation transformations on those layers as the users scrolls within a circle by using angles.

Answer (score 0):

What that video is displaying was probably not done with a UIScrollView. Most likely look into CoreAnimation and putting each of those screens into a layer for the background navigation screen.